# How can I search for a keyword across the questions I posted on an SE site and the answers that they received?

Tags: support, search

I posted several questions on one of the  Stack Exchange websites. How can I search for a keyword across these questions and the answers that the questions received? Ideally I'd also be interested to search through all the comments present on the page.

I tried `user:me is:question keyword` but it only search through my questions, not the answers present on the pages where my questions are located.

Comment: Remove `is:question` . SE search doesn't search comments... AFAIK the only alternative is SEDE as suggested in the previous comment or use a data-dumps and a third party tool (I have never tried this last option)